# How to test click outside in Karma/Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular6

I have my directive click outside:

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  @Output()
  public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick(targetElement) {
      const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
      if (!clickedInside) {
          this.clickOutside.emit(null);
      }
  }
}
```

What types of tests can I do to find out if it's working? And how can I test?

it is used in the components. As for example the modal. when I click outside of the modal it closes.

Comment: Too broad. We don't know what your directive does or what are you business rules.

Comment: edited, sorry bro

Comment: 1) you should test if the output emits the event correctly 2) you should test the output doesn't emit if the element doesn't contain your target 3) in your other components, you should test if they respond to the output accordingly

Comment: Thankss! Do you have an example of any of these tests ?

Comment: Those are basic tests, are you new to unit testing ? If so, I can offer you to look at Angular documentation about testing, and tomorrow I'll give you examples (I'm on phone right now). If you're not, start by mocking your event emitter and element ref so that they fit each test.

Comment: I've already done some simple component testing. But it's my first with directives. I searched some examples but could not apply with the click outside. If you can help me a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

```
 import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 import { ClickOutsideDirective } from '../p6-click-outside.directive';

@Component({
template: `<div (clickOutside)='onClick($event)' clickOutside> Click Outside this </div>
<button>This is outside<button>`
})
class TestClickOutsideComponent {

public active: boolean = false;

onClick() {
    this.active = !this.active;
}

}
fdescribe('P6ClickOutsideDirective', () => {
let component: TestClickOutsideComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestClickOutsideComponent>;
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ClickOutsideDirective, TestClickOutsideComponent]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestClickOutsideComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

fit('should create component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
});

fit('it should call onClick method when clicked on the div element', async(() => {
    const activeValueBeforeClick = component.active;
    const debugEl: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const div: HTMLElement = debugEl.querySelector('div');
    div.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(activeValueBeforeClick).toBe(component.active);
```

This will work when you testing while clicking on the div eleent, One more condition you have to write when clicked outside, which i am not able to write properly.seems event is not getting emitted!

Comment: That's the problem. We can't emit the event until we click outside the fixture element. Do you know how can we emit event outside fixture.